# Seekbar progress changed but GLSurface view not affected

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview, android-seekbar

I am developing app in which i want to give brightness to my GLsurfaceView on progress changed of Seekbar. The progress changed but GLsurfaceView can't be effected means i can't increment or decrement brightness eventhough color are also not applied to GLSurfaceview.. I have tried for that. But nothing happen. Appropriate for your help Thanks in Advance!!

***My Code is Here:***

EffectActivity.java:

```
public class EffectsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnTouchListener, OnClickListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener, Renderer {

QuickAction quickAction;
SeekBar progress_seekbar;
String pos, mine;
private FilterAdjuster mFilterAdjuster;
private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
private static final int NONE = 0;
private static final int DRAG = 1;
private static final int ZOOM = 2;
private int mode = NONE;
private PointF start = new PointF();
private PointF mid = new PointF();
private float oldDist = 1f;
private float d = 0f;
private float newRot = 0f;
private float[] lastEvent = null;
int count = 0;
Button btnSave, btnEffects, btnWallpaper;
ImageFilters imgFilter;
ProgressDialog pDialog, pd;
Bitmap myBmp, bmp;
MainLayout mainLayout;
FrameLayout fm;
ConnectionDetector cd;
private static ListView lvMenu;
Button btMenu, btnseting;
TextView tvTitle;
ImageView iv;
private static final int ID_SAVE = 1;
private static final int ID_WALLPAPER = 2;
private static final int ID_RATE = 3;
LinearLayout l1, l2, l3, main;
ArrayList<String> mList;
private GLSurfaceView mEffectView;
private int[] mTextures = new int[2];
private EffectContext mEffectContext;
private Effect mEffect;
private TextureRenderer mTexRenderer = new TextureRenderer();
private int mImageWidth;
private int mImageHeight;
private boolean mInitialized = false;
int mCurrentEffect;
private volatile boolean saveFrame;
ArrayList<Bitmap> bimList;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

public void setCurrentEffect(int effect) {
    mCurrentEffect = effect;

}

Handler h = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        Toast.makeText(EffectsActivity.this,
                "Wallpaper set. Your Image saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        SharedPreferences spdata = getSharedPreferences("Image", 0);
        String image = spdata.getString("imageshare", "");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(image);
        ShareAlertDialog(uri);
    }

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mainLayout = (MainLayout) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.myfile, null);
    setContentView(mainLayout);
    mEffectView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.effectsview);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    mEffectView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

    mEffectView.setRenderer(this);
    mEffectView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    mCurrentEffect = 0;
    mList = new ArrayList<String>();
    bimList = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(EffectsActivity.this);
    findIDforXML();

    Intent n = getIntent();
    pos = n.getStringExtra("position");
    Log.v("My Position", pos);

    if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

        GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
        task.execute(pos);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
                EffectsActivity.this,
                "No Internet Connection available. Please try again later or reconnect to it.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    showQucickAction();

    showEffectsList();
    lvMenu.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.custom_row_item, R.id.title, mList));
    lvMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            setCurrentEffect(position);
            mEffectView.requestRender();
            mainLayout.toggleMenu();
        }

    });

}

public void toggleMenu(View v) {
    mainLayout.toggleMenu();
}


public void findIDforXML() {

    lvMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_menu_listview);
    tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_content_title);
    progress_seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    progress_seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    btMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_content_button_menu);
    fm = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment);
    btnseting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsetting);
    l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l1);
    l2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l2);
    l3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l3);
    main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    // btnseting.setOnClickListener(this);
    btMenu.setOnClickListener(this);

}
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // switch (v.getId()) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.activity_main_content_button_menu:

        toggleMenu(v);

        break;

    case R.id.btnsetting:
        // quickAction.show(v);

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, final int progress,
        final boolean fromUser) {

    if (mFilterAdjuster != null) {
        mFilterAdjuster.adjust(progress);
    }

    mEffectView.requestRender();

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(final SeekBar seekBar) {
}

private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EffectsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Please Wait.");
        pDialog.setMessage("Displaying Image");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap map = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            Log.v("URL", url);
            map = downloadImage(url);
            mine = encodeTobase64(map);

        }
        return map;
    }

    // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // myBmp = result;
        // mGPUImageView.setImage(myBmp);

        pDialog.dismiss();
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Bitmap", 0);
        editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putString("imagePreferance", mine);
        editor.commit();

    }

    // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        try {
            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            Log.v("MyUrl", url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            stream.close();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
        return stream;
    }
}

public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory
            .decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/screenshot.png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

public void showEffectsList() {

    mList.add("None");
    mList.add("Autofix");
    mList.add("Bw");
    mList.add("Brightness");
    mList.add("Contrast");
    mList.add("Crossprocess");
    mList.add("Documentary");
    mList.add("Duotone");
    mList.add("Filllight");
    mList.add("Fisheye");
    mList.add("Fliphor");
    mList.add("flipvert");
    mList.add("Grain");
    mList.add("Grayscale");
    mList.add("Lomoish");
    mList.add("Negative");
    mList.add("Posterize");
    mList.add("Rotate");
    mList.add("Saturate");
    mList.add("Sepia");
    mList.add("Sharpen");
    mList.add("Temperature");
    mList.add("Tint");
    mList.add("Vignette");

}

private void loadTextures() {
    // Generate textures

    GLES20.glGenTextures(2, mTextures, 0);
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Bitmap", 0);
    String bmpValue = sp.getString("imagePreferance", "");

    Bitmap bitmapObject = decodeBase64(bmpValue);

    if (bitmapObject != null) {

        mImageWidth = bitmapObject.getWidth();
        mImageHeight = bitmapObject.getHeight();
        mTexRenderer.updateTextureSize(mImageWidth, mImageHeight);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmapObject, 0);
        GLToolbox.initTexParams();

    }

}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mInitialized = false;

    if (!mInitialized) {
        // Only need to do this once
        mEffectContext = EffectContext.createWithCurrentGlContext();
        mTexRenderer.init();
        loadTextures();
        mEffectView.requestRender();
        mInitialized = true;

    }
    if (mCurrentEffect != 0) {
        // if an effect is chosen initialize it and apply it to the texture
        initEffect();
        applyEffect();
    }
    renderResult();
    if (saveFrame) {

        final Bitmap mp = takeScreenshot(gl);
        saveBitmap(mp);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        final int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        final int width = metrics.widthPixels;

        final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                .getInstance(EffectsActivity.this);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                // // method stub
                try {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        Looper.prepare();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(mp);
                    wallpaperManager
                            .suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
                    h.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }).start();
        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mp,
                "MyImage", null);

        SharedPreferences spdata = getSharedPreferences("Image", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edt = spdata.edit();
        edt.putString("imageshare", path);
        edt.commit();

        saveFrame = false;

    }

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.e("SurfaceView ", "Changed");
    if (mTexRenderer != null) {
        mTexRenderer.updateViewSize(width, height);
        mInitialized = false;

    }

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.e("SurfaceView ", "Created");

}

private void initEffect() {
    EffectFactory effectFactory = mEffectContext.getFactory();
    if (mEffect != null) {
        mEffect.release();
    }
    /**
     * Initialize the correct effect based on the selected menu/action item
     */
    switch (mCurrentEffect) {

    case 0:
        break;

    case 1:
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_AUTOFIX);
        mEffect.setParameter("scale", 0.5f);
        break;

    case 2:
        mEffect = effectFactory
                .createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_BLACKWHITE);
        mEffect.setParameter("black", .1f);
        mEffect.setParameter("white", .7f);
        break;

    case 3:
        mEffect = effectFactory
                .createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_BRIGHTNESS);
        mEffect.setParameter("brightness", 2.0f);
        break;

    case 4:
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_CONTRAST);
        mEffect.setParameter("contrast", 1.4f);
        break;

    case 5:
        mEffect = effectFactory
                .createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_CROSSPROCESS);
        break;

    case 6:
        mEffect = effectFactory
                .createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_DOCUMENTARY);
        break;

    case 7:
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_DUOTONE);
        mEffect.setParameter("first_color", Color.YELLOW);
        mEffect.setParameter("second_color", Color.DKGRAY);
        break;

    case 8:
        mEffect = effectFactory
                .createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_FILLLIGHT);
        mEffect.setParameter("strength", .8f);
        break;

    case 9:
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_FISHEYE);
        mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
        break;

    case 10:
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_FLIP);
        mEffect.setParameter("vertical", true);
        break;

    case 11:
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_FLIP);
        mEffect.setParameter("horizontal", true);
        break;

    case 12:
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_GRAIN);
        mEffect.setParameter("strength", 1.0f);
        break;

    case 13:
        mEffect = effectFactory
                .createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_GRAYSCALE);
        break;

    case 14:
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_LOMOISH);
        break;

    case 15:
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
        break;

    case 16:
        mEffect = effectFactory
                .createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_POSTERIZE);
        break;

    case 17:
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_ROTATE);
        mEffect.setParameter("angle", 180);
        break;

    case 18:
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_SATURATE);
        mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
        break;

    case 19:
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_SEPIA);
        break;

    case 20:
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_SHARPEN);
        break;

    case 21:
        mEffect = effectFactory
                .createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_TEMPERATURE);
        mEffect.setParameter("scale", .9f);
        break;

    case 22:
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_TINT);
        mEffect.setParameter("tint", Color.MAGENTA);
        break;

    case 23:
        mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_VIGNETTE);
        mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
        break;

    default:
        break;

    }
}

private void applyEffect() {
    mEffect.apply(mTextures[0], mImageWidth, mImageHeight, mTextures[1]);

}

private void renderResult() {
    if (mCurrentEffect != 0) {
        // if no effect is chosen, just render the original bitmap
        mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[1]);
    } else {
        // render the result of applyEffect()
        mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[0]);
    }
}

public Bitmap takeScreenshot(GL10 mGL) {

    final int mWidth = mEffectView.getWidth();
    final int mHeight = mEffectView.getHeight();
    IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.allocate(mWidth * mHeight);
    IntBuffer ibt = IntBuffer.allocate(mWidth * mHeight);
    mGL.glReadPixels(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GL10.GL_RGBA,
            GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);

    // Convert upside down mirror-reversed image to right-side up normal
    // image.
    for (int i = 0; i < mHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mWidth; j++) {
            ibt.put((mHeight - i - 1) * mWidth + j, ib.get(i * mWidth + j));
        }
    }

    Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ibt);

    return mBitmap;
}

public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.d("Image Log:", imageEncoded);
    return imageEncoded;
}

public void MyClick(View v) {
    saveFrame = true;
    mEffectView.requestRender();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    if (mEffectView != null) {
        mEffectView.onResume();
    }

}

 }
```

***GLTool.java:***

```
public class GLToolbox {
final LinkedList<Runnable> mRunOnDraw;
private final String mVertexShader;
private final String mFragmentShader;
protected int mGLProgId;
protected int mGLAttribPosition;
protected int mGLUniformTexture;
protected int mGLAttribTextureCoordinate;
int mOutputWidth;
int mOutputHeight;
boolean mIsInitialized;
public static final String NO_FILTER_VERTEX_SHADER = ""
        + "attribute vec4 position;\n"
        + "attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;\n" + " \n"
        + "varying vec2 textureCoordinate;\n" + " \n" + "void main()\n"
        + "{\n" + "    gl_Position = position;\n"
        + "    textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;\n" + "}";
public static final String NO_FILTER_FRAGMENT_SHADER = ""
        + "varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;\n"
        + " \n"
        + "uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;\n"
        + " \n"
        + "void main()\n"
        + "{\n"
        + "     gl_FragColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);\n"
        + "}";

public GLToolbox() {
    this(NO_FILTER_VERTEX_SHADER, NO_FILTER_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
}

public GLToolbox(final String vertexShader, final String fragmentShader) {
    mRunOnDraw = new LinkedList<Runnable>();
    mVertexShader = vertexShader;
    mFragmentShader = fragmentShader;
}

public static int loadShader(int shaderType, String source) {
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType);
    if (shader != 0) {
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
        int[] compiled = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
        if (compiled[0] == 0) {
            String info = GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader);
            GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
            shader = 0;
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not compile shader "
                    + shaderType + ":" + info);
        }
    }
    return shader;
}

public static int createProgram(String vertexSource, String fragmentSource) {
    int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
    if (vertexShader == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    int pixelShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource);
    if (pixelShader == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    if (program != 0) {
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        checkGlError("glAttachShader");
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
        checkGlError("glAttachShader");
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
        int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
        if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
            String info = GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program);
            GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program);
            program = 0;
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not link program: " + info);
        }
    }
    return program;
}

public static void checkGlError(String op) {
    int error;
    while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
        throw new RuntimeException(op + ": glError " + error);
    }
}

public static void initTexParams() {
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
}

public static class FilterAdjuster {
    private final Adjuster<? extends GLToolbox> adjuster;

    public FilterAdjuster(final GLToolbox filter) {
        if (filter instanceof GPUImageSharpenFilter) {
            adjuster = new SharpnessAdjuster().filter(filter);
        } else {
            adjuster = null;
        }
    }

    public void adjust(final int percentage) {
        if (adjuster != null) {
            adjuster.adjust(percentage);
        }
    }

    private abstract class Adjuster<T extends GLToolbox> {
        private T filter;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public Adjuster<T> filter(final GLToolbox filter) {
            this.filter = (T) filter;
            return this;
        }

        public T getFilter() {
            return filter;
        }

        public abstract void adjust(int percentage);

        protected float range(final int percentage, final float start,
                final float end) {
            return (end - start) * percentage / 100.0f + start;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        protected int range(final int percentage, final int start,
                final int end) {
            return (end - start) * percentage / 100 + start;
        }
    }

    private class SharpnessAdjuster extends Adjuster<GPUImageSharpenFilter> {
        @Override
        public void adjust(final int percentage) {
            getFilter().setSharpness(range(percentage, -4.0f, 4.0f));
        }
    }

}

public void onOutputSizeChanged(final int width, final int height) {
    mOutputWidth = width;
    mOutputHeight = height;
}

public void onInit() {
    mGLProgId = com.example.photoeffects.extra.OpenGlUtils.loadProgram(
            mVertexShader, mFragmentShader);
    mGLAttribPosition = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mGLProgId, "position");
    mGLUniformTexture = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mGLProgId,
            "inputImageTexture");
    mGLAttribTextureCoordinate = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mGLProgId,
            "inputTextureCoordinate");
    mIsInitialized = true;
}

public void onInitialized() {
}

public final void destroy() {
    mIsInitialized = false;
    GLES20.glDeleteProgram(mGLProgId);
    onDestroy();
}

public void onDestroy() {
}

protected void setFloat(final int location, final float floatValue) {

    GLES20.glUniform1f(location, floatValue);

}
```

***GPUImageSharpenFilter.java:***

```
public class GPUImageSharpenFilter extends GLToolbox {
public static final String SHARPEN_VERTEX_SHADER = ""
        + "attribute vec4 position;\n"
        + "attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;\n"
        + "\n"
        + "uniform float imageWidthFactor; \n"
        + "uniform float imageHeightFactor; \n"
        + "uniform float sharpness;\n"
        + "\n"
        + "varying vec2 textureCoordinate;\n"
        + "varying vec2 leftTextureCoordinate;\n"
        + "varying vec2 rightTextureCoordinate; \n"
        + "varying vec2 topTextureCoordinate;\n"
        + "varying vec2 bottomTextureCoordinate;\n"
        + "\n"
        + "varying float centerMultiplier;\n"
        + "varying float edgeMultiplier;\n"
        + "\n"
        + "void main()\n"
        + "{\n"
        + "    gl_Position = position;\n"
        + "    \n"
        + "    mediump vec2 widthStep = vec2(imageWidthFactor, 0.0);\n"
        + "    mediump vec2 heightStep = vec2(0.0, imageHeightFactor);\n"
        + "    \n"
        + "    textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;\n"
        + "    leftTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy - widthStep;\n"
        + "    rightTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy + widthStep;\n"
        + "    topTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy + heightStep;     \n"
        + "    bottomTextureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy - heightStep;\n"
        + "    \n" + "    centerMultiplier = 1.0 + 4.0 * sharpness;\n"
        + "    edgeMultiplier = sharpness;\n" + "}";

public static final String SHARPEN_FRAGMENT_SHADER = ""
        + "precision highp float;\n"
        + "\n"
        + "varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;\n"
        + "varying highp vec2 leftTextureCoordinate;\n"
        + "varying highp vec2 rightTextureCoordinate; \n"
        + "varying highp vec2 topTextureCoordinate;\n"
        + "varying highp vec2 bottomTextureCoordinate;\n"
        + "\n"
        + "varying highp float centerMultiplier;\n"
        + "varying highp float edgeMultiplier;\n"
        + "\n"
        + "uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;\n"
        + "\n"
        + "void main()\n"
        + "{\n"
        + "    mediump vec3 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate).rgb;\n"
        + "    mediump vec3 leftTextureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, leftTextureCoordinate).rgb;\n"
        + "    mediump vec3 rightTextureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, rightTextureCoordinate).rgb;\n"
        + "    mediump vec3 topTextureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, topTextureCoordinate).rgb;\n"
        + "    mediump vec3 bottomTextureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, bottomTextureCoordinate).rgb;\n"
        + "\n"
        + "    gl_FragColor = vec4((textureColor * centerMultiplier - (leftTextureColor * edgeMultiplier + rightTextureColor * edgeMultiplier + topTextureColor * edgeMultiplier + bottomTextureColor * edgeMultiplier)), texture2D(inputImageTexture, bottomTextureCoordinate).w);\n"
        + "}";

private int mSharpnessLocation;
private float mSharpness;
private int mImageWidthFactorLocation;
private int mImageHeightFactorLocation;

public GPUImageSharpenFilter() {
    this(0.0f);
}

public GPUImageSharpenFilter(final float sharpness) {
    super(SHARPEN_VERTEX_SHADER, SHARPEN_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    mSharpness = sharpness;
}

@Override
public void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    mSharpnessLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(createProgram("", "sharpness"),
            "sharpness");
    mImageWidthFactorLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(createProgram("", "imageWidthFactor"),
            "imageWidthFactor");
    mImageHeightFactorLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(createProgram("", "imageHeightFactor"),
            "imageHeightFactor");
    setSharpness(mSharpness);
}

@Override
public void onOutputSizeChanged(final int width, final int height) {
    super.onOutputSizeChanged(width, height);
    setFloat(mImageWidthFactorLocation, 1.0f / width);
    setFloat(mImageHeightFactorLocation, 1.0f / height);
}

public void setSharpness(final float sharpness) {
    mSharpness = sharpness;
    setFloat(mSharpnessLocation, mSharpness);
}
  }
```

Comment: Please try to strip down your code to the necessary part.

Comment: Here i need to add all the things which belongs to that. so it is necessary code.

Comment: I don't think including your base64 converter, bitmap saver, GL program compiler, and so on are relevant.  If you really don't know if these functions are involved then I'd recommend spending a bit more time debugging the problem.  It would also help to describe briefly what approach you're using to specify the brightness and what you've tried so far to narrow the problem down -- all I can tell is that you're trying to control the brightness, something didn't work, and there's a big pile of code.

Comment: @Piyush Did you solve this?