# Crashing Android App on Rotating screen with AsyncTask

Tags: android

My Android App is crashing when I'm rotating the screen with `ProgressBar` and an `AsyncTask` running. Can somebody help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Post the logcat error and the code where progress bar is started in async task.

Comment: If your app crashed then you have to post your logcat with particular exception.

Comment: Show your AsyncTask class...

Comment: Got answer need to "android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" line to activity in manifest file..Thanks for your help!! Got this answer from "Application Crashes on orientation change while showing Progress Bar in AsyncTask" this stack overflow question.

Comment: Put some code for more information so we help you out.

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate screen than your `AsyncTask` start again as per this question [How to handle an AsyncTask during Screen Rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2620917/942224) and `onResume` also gets called. so may be your `ProgressBar` refrenceing `null`.

so use this to handle

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`  in your `Activity` tag in Manifest file.

Comment: Check this .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348006/seekbar-progress-changed-but-glsurface-view-not-affected.

Answer (score 0):

try using this block of code in the asyncTask, it worked pretty much for me.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {

        //stuff that updates ui
          }
        });
```